# Change Telerik's ASP.NET RadToolbar Skin with client-side code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, telerik

I am using a RadToolbar Control within a page where almost there is **no post back**.
One of the features that this page has, is multiple themes.

Now, I need to set the skin of the RadToolbar based on my theme. 
I see that the client side API of the RadToolbar object contains a "get_skin" method which correctly returns the name of the server-side-assigned skin name. But the object has no "set_skin" method.

All I am asking is that whether there is a way to change a toolbar's skin which client side code, or not; and if not, what other ways do you suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did fix the problem somehow. This is a funny one.

1. I found the different stylesheet files that where rendered in my page by `RadToolbar` for different themes.
   For each skin (i.e. 'Black') the css classes will be rendered for that skin (i.e. 'RadToolbar_Black')
2. I added those stylesheets to my own code and downloaded every image used in those css classes. After that I changed the url() addresses to my saved image files. Also I replaced skin names (i.e. '_Black') to '_Default'
   (The Stylesheet file and images both are web resources in `Telerik.Web.UI` assembly and are referenced using `WebResource.axd` handler.)
3. For each of my themes I created a separate `.css` file.
4. Now I disabled telerik's skin. Propertis `EnableEmbeddedSkins` and `EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet` did that.
5. Set RadToolbar's Skin to 'Default' or just omit the assignment.
6. Finally what I needed to do is to use Javascript to switch between those css files to change the toolbar's theme.